# WebApi Put "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, self-hosting

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly List<Contact> _contacts = new List<Contact>();
    public Contact PutContacts(int id, Contact contact)
    {
        if (_contacts.Any(c => c.Id == contact.Id) == false)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        contact.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
        return contact;
    }
}
```

http put header:

```
PUT /api/contacts/3 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
```

body:

```
{"Id":3,"Name":"mmm","Phone":"000 000 0000","Email":"mmm@gmail.com","LastModified":"2012-03-08T23:42:13.8681395+08:00"}
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'SelfHost.Contact PutContacts(Int32, SelfHost.Contact)' in 'SelfHost.ContactsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
```

Why? thanks.

PS:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the issue you are describing.

Model:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    public Contact Put(int id, Contact contact)
    {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{""Id"":3,""Name"":""mmm"",""Phone"":""000 000 0000"",""Email"":""mmm@gmail.com"",""LastModified"":""2012-03-08T23:42:13.8681395+08:00""}");
            var result = client.UploadData("http://localhost:1405/api/contacts/4", "PUT", data);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the client, the following request is being sent:

```
PUT /api/contacts/4 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:1405
Content-Length: 119
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"Id":3,"Name":"mmm","Phone":"000 000 0000","Email":"mmm@gmail.com","LastModified":"2012-03-08T23:42:13.8681395+08:00"}
```

and I get the correct result from the server. So I guess that the request you are showing is not the actual request that's being sent to the server.

Comment: I tried your code.but error is exits. I try in  VS11 beta & mvc4 web api.

Answer (score 2):

I am having this same issue. The query parameter, "id" is null and the object "contact" is filled in. I think this is a model binding issue. If you put a break point in the controller, look at this expression:

```
this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

You will see that the value is there in the route data; its just not getting set on the model. I have an ActionFilter and if I put a break point in there as well, I see that the actionContext's ActionArgument has a key for it, but a null value.

Im still researching...

Comment: FYI, I also also using VS.NET 11 Beta.

Comment: I posted this as a bug to the Web API team. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/46

Comment: This is a confirmed bug in VS.NET 11 beta. It has already been fixed in the source of the codeplex link, but there isnt an official release yet.

Answer (score 0):

craigtadlock, thanks for your help and sending the bug over to Microsoft. I was having the same problem with PUTs. None of them worked. As a workaround, I hacked POST to handle PUT. If the object I'm posting to the server already has it's ID, the POST code treats it as a PUT with that ID. Pseudo code is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<MyClass> PostMyClass(MyClass myObject)
{
    if( myObject.ID != 0 ){
         //do PUT code
    }else{
         //do POST code
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually simply removing the ID parameter from teh server side PUT handler works better: 
public HttpResponseMessage<MyClass> PutMyClass(MyClass myObject)
{
    if( myObject.ID == 0 ){
         //return error
    }else{
         if( myObject exists ) 
             // do put code
         else
             // return NOT_FOUND code
    }
}